# Loopback - How to maintain roles

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I 'm using the latest version of `loopback` and I have created roles following [this](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html) guide. Unfortunately when I terminate node and start it again all the roles associated with users are gone. Is it possible, just using loopback's functionalities, to maintain that list?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Role.create({
      name: 'admin'
    }, function(err, role) {
      if (err) cb(err);

      //make bob an admin
      role.principals.create({
        principalType: RoleMapping.USER,
        principalId: users[2].id
      }, function(err, principal) {
        cb(err);
      });
    });
```

This part of your link creates a row in the `Role`, and `RoleMapping` table so it should persist along with anything else you save.  You are either using the `memory` datasource or somebody is resetting your database when you're not looking.